# System.InvalidCastException in Xamarin.forms application after adding MasterDetailPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have created a Xamarin forms application which stores user entered data in sqlite database and then shows in a list. Till this point everything was working perfectly fine. The data was being stored and retrieved properly. I then add a MasterDetailPage following a tutorial. The application builds successfully but it gives **System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid In mgmain JNI_OnLoad**. exception in MainActivitiy.cs  **LoadApplication(new App());** method.  After a good search, I can't figure out where could the problem be.

This is App.cs where MainMenuPage is a MasterDetailPage

```
namespace MyListXamarinForms
{

  public class App : Application
    {

        public App()
        {

            MainPage = new MainMenuPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

MainMenuPage.xaml (which is the masterpage that includes MasterPage and Detail - given below)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  x:Class="MyListXamarinForms.MainMenuPage"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyListXamarinForms">

  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:MasterPage x:Name="master"/>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>

  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <local:DetailPage/>
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

MainMenuPage.xaml.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyListXamarinForms
{
    public partial class MainMenuPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainMenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            master.ListViews.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;
        }

        private void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
            if(item!=null)
            {
                Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
                master.ListViews.SelectedItem = null;
                IsPresented = false;
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

MasterPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyListXamarinForms.MasterPage"
             Icon=""
             Title="Menu"
             Padding="0,50,0,0">
  <ContentPage.Content >
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <ListView x:Name="MenuList" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Label x:Name="ItemNameLabel" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
      </ListView>          
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

MasterPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyListXamarinForms
{
    public partial class MasterPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ListView ListViews { get { return MenuList; } }
        public MasterPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var masterPageItem = new List<MasterPageItem>();

            //AddItem and HomePage are two ContentPages with content
            masterPageItem.Add(new MasterPageItem {
                Title = "Add Item",
                TargetType = typeof(AddItem)
            });
            masterPageItem.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "View Item List",
                TargetType = typeof(HomePage)
            });

            MenuList.ItemsSource = masterPageItem;
        }
    }
}
```

MasterPageItem.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyListXamarinForms
{
    public class MasterPageItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MyListXamarinForms.Droid
MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace MyListXamarinForms.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "MyListXamarinForms", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());  //Exception thrown here
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: It is something you do in your master-detail page. Without the code it is impossible to say

Comment: @YuriS I have updated the post with my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen at app launch? Do you have any custom renderers by any chance? Also check the build output closely, sometimes there is some useful information in there although you will have to dig through it for a bit.

Comment: Just to make it simpler, can you share publicly this sample project?

Comment: for example you are missing code of AddItem and HomePage. The problem can be there too

Answer (score 7):

In your case you don't need an ImageCell since you're just showing a label, but a DataTemplate for a ListView must be a Cell, so you could either do this:

```
<DataTemplate> 
    <TextCell x:Name="ItemNameLabel" Text="{Binding Title}"/> 
</DataTemplate>
```

- TextCell is simple a cell with a label.

Or this:

```
 <DataTemplate> 
     <ViewCell>
        <Label x:Name="ItemNameLabel" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

- Note how this is just wrapping the label in a ViewCell

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same issue. I'm trying to customize my master page and the problem is that you're putting only a "label" inside the DataTemplate when it's expecting to receive an "ImageCell", thus the "invalid cast" exception.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyListXamarinForms.MasterPage"
         Icon=""
         Title="Menu"
         Padding="0,50,0,0">
<ContentPage.Content >
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <ListView x:Name="MenuList" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ImageCell Text="{Binding Title}" ImageSource="{Binding IconSource}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
      </ListView>          
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Replace the DataTemplate with the code above and it should work. Although if anyone has any idea how to customize the DataTemplate to put something else than an ImageCell I would be happy to know !

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use CollectionView rather than ListView. It has a custom DataTemplate and an EmptyView which helps a lot.
intro: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction

```
<CollectionView x:Name="MenuList">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <...Your cell here...>
      </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>            
  </CollectionView>
```

I got rid of the exception with that, and no prob since.